# How to limit paging in Django admin without changing the results number

Tags: python, django, pagination, paginator

I have a Django admin page and i wish to limit the number of pages without changing the number of objects in ChangeList.

E.g. I have ChangeList with 1000 results, limit 20 results per page.and i wish to limit paging offset to 10 pages but still present i have 1000 results. So the user will be able to see the count but won't be able to "jump" to the "far" offset.

Comment: You'll need to create a custom [pagination template tag](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7cbcf2e2cbca1acfccfd973f746a9e6abfc0052e/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#L47) then [override the admin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template) for [change_list.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a hint from [@bdoubleu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8741781/bdoubleu) i found out a simple elegant solution:

1. in `templates/admin/change_list.html` added :

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% block pagination %}{% limited_pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
```

2. in `templatetags/admin_list.py` (although i assume any other locations will work also) added:

```
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags import admin_list

@register.inclusion_tag('admin/pagination.html', takes_context=True)
def limited_pagination(context, cl):
    if somecondition:
        cl.paginator._num_pages = 20
    return admin_list.pagination(cl)
```